# Bug or error when attempting to append process to list/array and return

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

When attempting to append process id to list inside `processing_task` the list is changed but when attempting to return it from function it is unchanged for some reason I don't understand what the problem is...
Goal is :

> 1.Pass all_process list to function
>
> 2.Append process id to list
>
> 3.Get that appended list returned
>
> 4.Passed onto function that can terminate the process(in this case `keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+q', kill_all(a_processes=xzy))`)

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process, Pool

from multiprocessing.managers import NamespaceProxy, BaseManager
import inspect  # part of multiprocessing stuff
import time
import keyboard
import os


class ObjProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    """Returns a proxy instance for any user defined data-type. The proxy instance will have the namespace and
    functions of the data-type (except private/protected callables/attributes). Furthermore, the proxy will be
    pickable and can its state can be shared among different processes. """

    @classmethod
    def populate_obj_attributes(cls, real_cls):
        DISALLOWED = set(dir(cls))
        ALLOWED = ['__sizeof__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__le__', '__repr__', '__dict__', '__lt__',
                   '__gt__']
        DISALLOWED.add('__class__')
        new_dict = {}
        for (attr, value) in inspect.getmembers(real_cls, callable):
            if attr not in DISALLOWED or attr in ALLOWED:
                new_dict[attr] = cls._proxy_wrap(attr)
        return new_dict

    @staticmethod
    def _proxy_wrap(attr):
        """ This method creates function that calls the proxified object's method."""

        def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self._callmethod(attr, args, kwargs)

        return f


attributes = ObjProxy.populate_obj_attributes(Process)
ProcessProxy = type("ProcessProxy", (ObjProxy,), attributes)


def processing_task(function, normal_processes, combat_processes, all_processes,
                    arguments=None, append="ALL"):

    BaseManager.register('Process', Process, ProcessProxy, exposed=tuple(dir(ProcessProxy)))
    manager = BaseManager()
    manager.start()
    if arguments is None:
        start_function = manager.Process(target=function)
    else:
        start_function = manager.Process(target=function, args=arguments)

    # APPENDING
    if append == "ALL":
        all_processes.append(start_function)
        print(all_processes)  # THIS IS THE VALUE THAT SHOULD BE RETURNED        
    elif append == "no":
        normal_processes.append(start_function)
    elif append == "co":
        combat_processes.append(start_function)

    start_function.start()

    print(normal_processes, combat_processes, all_processes)
    n_processes = normal_processes
    c_processes = combat_processes
    a_processes = all_processes
    return n_processes, c_processes, a_processes


def counting():
    for i in range(1, 10, 1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)


def kill_all(a_processes):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("ATTEMPTING TO KILL : ", a_processes)
    for process in a_processes:
        # print(process)
        process.terminate()
        process.kill()
        process.join()
    exit()
    os._exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    listmanager = Manager()
    no_processes = listmanager.list()
    co_processes = listmanager.list()
    all_processes = listmanager.list()

    n, c, xzy = processing_task(counting, no_processes, co_processes, all_processes) 
    print("PRINTING ALL_PROC", all_processes) 
    print("xzy[all_processes] REMAINS UNCHANGED", xzy)# OUTPUTS VALUE Same as all_processes BEFORE processing_task SHOULD output value i mention inside processing_task

    keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+q', kill_all(a_processes=xzy))
```

Comment: Its unclear what you are expecting to happen. You created three lists, appended processes to one of them, and returned them. The output exactly reflects that. Show an expected output vs what you re getting now when you print the lists.

Comment: Did it. Hope its better now. The main focus is all_processes/a_processes and xzy values which should differ but they don't, they give same output with print